# Pair each row in between Dataframes and retain those without pair

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is it possible to get find the pair between two dataframes but it has duplicates.
If in df1 i have a pair with 3 instances and df2 i have only 2 instances of that pair I will retain only the ones that doesnt have a pair.

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'ID':[A, A, A, A,B,B,B,D], 'Value':[1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2,3]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'ID':[A,A,A,B,B,C], 'Value':[1,1,2,1,2,4]})
```

result:

```
remaining_df = pd.DataFrame(data={'ID':[A,B,B,C,D], 'Value':[1,1,2,4,3]})
```

Im thinking concatenating ID and value then Create a pivot then count of the concatenated text
I dont have any yet, im still exploring if its possible or can someone give me an idea/guide me what method to use.

Comment: first idea: `df1.groupby(]'ID', "Value"].count()` and the same for `df2` and later somehow subtract results and get `abs()` (but I don't know how to subtrack), And remove values which gives `0`

Comment: Thank you so much for guiding me. It really helps me a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Now I see some problem with my answer. For your example it works OK but if we add another `A1` in first `DataFrame` then it reduces it to single `A1` in result but it should give two `A1,A1`

This version can't be fixed with ie. `cumsum()` because it really needs `MultiIndex` like in other answer.

But I keep it maybe some elements will be useful for someone.

---

My first idea is to use `.groupby(["ID", "Value"])` to group elements (in every dataframe) with the same `ID` and `Value` and use `.size()` to count them - it gives two `Series`

```
series1 = df_1.groupby(["ID", "Value"]).size()
series2 = df_2.groupby(["ID", "Value"]).size()
```

```
ID  Value
A   1        3
    2        1
B   1        2
    2        1
D   3        1
dtype: int64


ID  Value
A   1        2
    2        1
B   1        1
    2        1
C   4        1
dtype: int64
```

Later it needs to subtract these `Series` - but using `s1 - s2` it gives values `NaN` for values `C` and `D` because they exist only in one `Series`.
It needs `.subtract(... fill_value=0)` to fill missing elements.

And it needs `.abs()` to convert negative values to positive values.

```
series = series1.subtract(series2, fill_value=0)
series = series.abs()
```

```
ID  Value
A   1        1.0
    2        0.0
B   1        1.0
    2        0.0
C   4        1.0
D   3        1.0
dtype: float64
```

Now it needs to drop results which gives `0`

```
series = series[ series[0] != 0 ]
```

```
ID  Value
A   1        1.0
B   1        1.0
C   4        1.0
D   3        1.0
dtype: float64
```

And finally it needs to clean it up - reset index, remove column with `size` (column `0`). And reset gives back `DataFrame`

```
df = series.reset_index().drop(columns=[0])
```

```
  ID  Value
0  A      1
1  B      1
2  C      4
3  D      3
```

---

Full working code:

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'ID':["A","A","A","A","B","B","B","D"], 'Value':[1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2,3]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'ID':["A","A","A","B","B","C"], 'Value':[1,1,2,1,2,4]})

series1 = df_1.groupby(["ID", "Value"]).size()   # Series
series2 = df_2.groupby(["ID", "Value"]).size()   # Series

print('\n--- series1 groupby.size ---\n')
print(series1)
print('\n--- series2 groupby.size ---\n')
print(series2)

series = series1.subtract(series2, fill_value=0).abs()  # Series

print('\n--- series subtract.abs ---\n')
print(series)

series = series[ series != 0 ]  # Series

print('\n--- series drop ---\n')
print(series)

df = series.reset_index().drop(columns=[0])  # DataFrame

print('\n--- df clean ---\n')

print(df)
```

Result:

```
--- series1 groupby.size ---

ID  Value
A   1        3
    2        1
B   1        2
    2        1
D   3        1
dtype: int64

--- series2 groupby.size ---

ID  Value
A   1        2
    2        1
B   1        1
    2        1
C   4        1
dtype: int64

--- series subtract.abs ---

ID  Value
A   1        1.0
    2        0.0
B   1        1.0
    2        0.0
C   4        1.0
D   3        1.0
dtype: float64

--- series drop ---

ID  Value
A   1        1.0
B   1        1.0
C   4        1.0
D   3        1.0
dtype: float64

--- df clean ---

  ID  Value
0  A      1
1  B      1
2  C      4
3  D      3
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much. I made this as my guide. So what i did is group it by id and value. Then count how many of it is in df1 and df2. Then subtract. Result is positive i retain it in df1 then repeat the row based on the number of result

Comment: if you created better code then you could describe it as answer :) And you can mark your answer as accepted, and later you can upvote your answer. It may be useful for other users.

Answer (score 1):

I think we can simply use MultiIndex as follow:

```py
# setup
A, B, C, D = 'ABCD'
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'ID':[A, A, A, A,B,B,B,D], 'Value':[1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'ID':[A,A,A,B,B,C], 'Value':[1,1,2,1,2,4]})


idval = ['ID', 'Value']  # because I'm lazy
a = df1.assign(k=df1.groupby(idval).cumcount())
b = df2.assign(k=df2.groupby(idval).cumcount())
df = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(
    a
).symmetric_difference(
    pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(b)
).to_frame(index=False).drop('k', axis=1)

>>> df
  ID  Value
0  A      1
1  B      1
2  C      4
3  D      3
```

#### Explanation

As @Furas correctly said, the first thing that comes to mind is to `.groupby(['ID', 'Value'])`. In this answer, we use `cumcount()` that just counts cumulatively within each group. In other words:

```py
>>> a
  ID  Value  k
0  A      1  0
1  A      1  1
2  A      1  2
3  A      2  0
4  B      1  0
5  B      1  1
6  B      2  0
7  D      3  0
```

Then, we use the ability of `MultiIndex` to do a symmetric difference (fast). To use that, we convert each frame (`a` and `b` with their `k` counters) into a `MultiIndex`, then we take the symmetric difference, and "hydrate" the result back into a frame. The whole operation should be reasonably fast.

Comment: could you describe it in answer? It seems important element is `symmetric_difference`

Comment: You are correct. Please see the edited answer to include an explanation.

Comment: I see another important element `cumsum()` - it keeps repeated elements . My version with `size()` probably will reduce it to single element.

Comment: I tested both versions with more `A1` in first DataFrame and your version really keeps repeated elements but my version reduces it to single `A1` - so it doesn't work as (probably) OP expects. And `cumsum()` can't repair it. It really needs MultiIndex.